# How to mount VeraCrypt full disk encrypted volume in read write mode under macOS?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, encryption, mount, ntfs

I am able to mount VeraCrypt full disk encrypted volume under macOS Sierra, but I am not able to write to it. The VeraCrypt disk shows read-only as false, but I don't have permission to write. The volume is formatted as NTFS. I tried with Paragon NTFS driver, the free version, but it does not work.

How to mount an NTFS volume as read-write?

Comment: Paragon's free version is only for Seagate drives. Is that what you have?

Comment: Mine is buffalo.

Comment: Then the free version won't work.

Comment: Which format should I choose in veracrypt so that it works with macOS and Windows without additional software?

Comment: I don't know the app at all, but ExFAT is the only large file-aware format that both can natively read & write